# Unmatched query within Select query

Tags: sql, ms-access

EDIT: This question was originally about a subset of my issue, but I think this heavliy revised version will be more helpful.

I have two tables:

`tPrevious`

```
PreviousNo| CODE   | DESCRIPTION
_______________________________  
A1        | Code1  | Desc 1
A2        | Code2a | Desc 2a
A2        | Code2b | Desc 2b
A2        | Code2c | Desc 2c-to-be-deleted
A3        | Code3a | Desc 3a
```

and `tCurrent`

```
CurrentNo | CODE  | DESCRIPTION
_______________________________  
A1        | Code1  | Desc 1
A2        | Code2a | Desc 2a-changed
A2        | Code2b | Desc 2b
A3        | Code3a | Desc 3a
A3        | Code3a | Desc 3b-new
```

I need to list the records with changes in the `DESCRIPTION` field. One for records added:

```
CurrentNo | CODE  | DESCRIPTION
_______________________________  

A2        | Code2a | Desc 2a-changed
A3        | Code3a | Desc 3b-new
```

...and one for those deleted:

```
A2        | Code2c | Desc 2c-to-be-deleted
```

I started with this query:

```
SELECT tCurrent.CurrentNo, tCurrent.CODE, tCurrent.Description
FROM tCurrent INNER JOIN tPrevious ON (tCurrent.CurrentNo = tPrevious.PreviousNo) AND (tCurrent.CODE = tPrevious.CODE)
GROUP BY tCurrent.CurrentNo, tCurrent.CODE, tCurrent.Description;
```

It lists all the new and changed records, but also those that are *unchanged*.  I can't figure out how to exclude them.

I thought I needed to add

`WHERE tCurrent.Description <> tPrevious.Description`

But that doesn't help.  And when I tried adding another JOIN, I got an error message about "ambiguous outer Joins"

(I'm working in Access, going back and forth between the SQL window and the Query Designer.)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is not returning any records because you have contradicting selection criteria: your join criteria is returning those records from `tprevious` whose `code` is equal to that in `tcurrent`, but your `where` clause is selecting those records for which the `code` is **not** equal...

You can actually perform the selection through the join criteria alone using the following:

```
select tc.currentno, tp.code, tc.code
from tcurrent tc inner join tprevious tp on tc.currentno = tp.previousno and tc.code <> tp.code
```

Here `tc` & `tp` are merely aliases for the table names, to avoid the need to type the full name for every reference.

Note that this type of query will not be able to be represented in the MS Access Query Designer, but only in the SQL View.

You can alternatively place the `code` selection in the `where` clause:

```
select tc.currentno, tp.code, tc.code
from tcurrent tc inner join tprevious tp on tc.currentno = tp.previousno
where tc.code <> tp.code
```

Comment: This is close to what I need, but it includes `code` that exists in both tables. I need to exclude those and show only "new" codes.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson Could you please edit your question to include sample data and a desired result?

Comment: Done. I'm afraid your answer will need to be heavily revised too!